# OPENROWSET() for Synapse dedicated pools?

Tags: azure-synapse

Any plans to support open row set for dedicated pools?
Advantages:

- More (and faster) parser options over `External File Format` such as row delimiter
- Can auto-infer schema
- More convenient to define the file format directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great feature request Anders. I see that you created already a feature request, I would encourage everyone to vote for it [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/b597e1af-0a25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8).